# Usergrid Setup - Cassandra Error

Tags: cassandra, usergrid

We are trying to setup Apache Usergrid 2.1, with the following configuration:

- CentOS 7
- Cassandra 1.2.19
- Oracle Java 1.8.0_91
- Tomcat 8.0.33
- ElasticSearch 2.3.2

Tomcat, Cassandra and ElasticSearch are running normally, there are no errors in the logs. However, when we deploy usergrid stack (ROOT.war), we get the following error in catalina.out and nothing works.

```
WARN Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl:31 - BadRequestException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=3(3), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace 'Usergrid_Applications' does not exist)
ERROR ServiceManager:110 - This should never happen
org.apache.usergrid.persistence.collection.exception.CollectionRuntimeException: An error occurred connecting to cassandra
```

This log is written almost every 5 seconds.

Since the application is not running, the proposed database setup urls do not work either.

Btw, we are following this document: https://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/deployment-guide.html

We also tried to generate the "Usergrid_Applications" keyspace manually, but that did not work either.

How can we make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was with the ElasticSearch version. When we install with the following configuration, setup was completed successfully.

- OpenJDK 1.8.0_91
- Tomcat 8.0.33
- Cassandra 1.2.19 (Datastax community distribution)
- ElasticSearch 1.4.5

The error log is very misleading btw.

Comment: I think you are correct. Usergrid 2.x currently requires ElasticSearch 1.4.x.

Comment: ElasticSearch 1.4 is a hard requirement. Cassandra 1.2.x is not so, I've tested with Cassandra 3.4 and it is working.

Comment: The documentation has been updated, and it says ES 1.7 is supported. https://github.com/apache/usergrid/blob/master/stack/README.md

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this problem for very long, i realized that in my case elasticsearch 1.7.6 as well as 2.x does not start without an additional config in **/etc/default/elasticsearch**.
Just adding this line **START_DAEMON=true** in the file and restarting elasticsearch worked for me.
Now able to connect to setup usergrid successfully with 1.7.6 (2.x is still not supported as the usergrid plugins are still [1.4.0.Beta1]). Had searched for the answer everywhere but could not find any reference till now. Hence thought of posting. 
I had almost given up on using usergrid due to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Keyspace 'Usergrid_Applications' does not exist.

Don't worry, just a warnning, because the keyspace can not be found in your Cassandra.

Just use the database setup api to init your DB, and this warnning will gone away.